# Attempting to calculate pi using chudnovsky algorithm in php

Tags: php, pi, approximation, calculus

I've been attempting to create some pi approximations using different methods, and the Chudnovsky algorithm looked fun, but I have hit a roadblock.

[image: roadblock]

Here's the code:

```
$pi =0;
for ($k = 0; $k < 1; $k++) {
    $pi += (($k%2==1?-1.0:1.0) * gmp_fact(6 * $k) * (13591409.0 + (545140134.0 * $k))) / (gmp_fact(3.0 * $k) * pow(gmp_fact($k), 3.0) * pow(640320.0, 3.0 * $k + 3.0/2.0));
}
$pi *= 12;
echo 1/$pi;
```

Running this gives me 301.59289474461.

I am new to php and thought this would be good training, so forgive me if this is amateur work.

I also realise there is a similar post in c++, which I attempted and was successful, but this is still broke. I've used stack exchange to solve many other problems, so i hope you can help!

Comment: https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2195&lngWId=8

Comment: Try changing your for loop condition to `$k < 99`, as this is a "convergent algorithm" and right now you're only executing the loop once (where `k==0`).

Comment: I have tried that, but the algorithm converges very quickly, so that 1 execution is enough to be accurate for many decimal places.                                   Any additional repetitions appear to give more decimal places, although beyond what I can see.

Comment: @Dagon hmm, This uses the "bcadd" etc. notation, so perhaps I have some precision problems in my code. Thanks for the link.

Comment: For any curious, the problem was he the denominator, my "pow(640320.0, 3.0 * $k + 3.0/2.0)" should have been "(pow(640320.0, 3.0 * $k + 1.0))*sqrt(640320.0)". For some reason it did not like the fraction.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have gmp extension installed, and Always use **gmp_strval()** when using gmp functions in php to avoid getting **the address of the gmp_fact object multiplied by other variables**.
From the php.net :  http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-fact.php#refsect1-function.gmp-fact-returnvalues

```
$pi =0;
for ($k = 0; $k < 20; $k++) {
    $pi += (($k%2==1?-1.0:1.0) * gmp_strval(gmp_fact(6 * $k)) * (13591409.0 + (545140134.0 * $k))) / ( gmp_strval(gmp_fact(3.0 * $k)) * pow( gmp_strval(gmp_fact($k)), 3.0) * pow(640320.0, 3.0 * $k + 3.0/2.0));
}
$pi *= 12;
echo 1/$pi;
```